# Media Player not working as expected

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am using MediaPlayer to run an audio file in my InternalDir. Here is the code:

```
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioPATH);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
```

I have put the above code in a try block logging IOException and IllegalArgumentException.

I have also added a onErrorListener. Here is the code:

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , "media player error");
```

...

I have also add an onCompletionListener. Here is the code :

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "media player on completion listener");
```

...

The service is destroyed after onstart and the logs are as follow:
[image]

No log entry for any error but still media player not working and service getting destroyed. can  anyone please explain why media player is not working?

Comment: STREAM_VOICE_CALL? tried different streams?

Comment: yes tried all streams.

Comment: when is relrelease() logged in the logcat? after your media real duration?

Comment: the audio is not played. it starts and then stops.

Comment: when is relrelease() logged in the logcat? after your media real duration?

Comment: Media player is released onDestory of the service.